# displaying image from php file (stored in mysql db)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to display an image stored in mysql database.
I store it this way:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['mod']) && (isset($_GET['upload'])) ) {
    if (isset($_FILES['image'])  && $_FILES['image']['size'] > 0) { 

    $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root");
    mysql_select_db("psi", $con);

      // Temporary file name stored on the server
      $tmpName  = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];  

      // Read the file 
      $fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
      $data = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
      $data = addslashes($data);
      fclose($fp);

      //now i use <tmpName> as an actual name of file
      $tmpName  = $_FILES['image']['name'];  
      if (isset($_GET['name']))
        $tmpName = $_GET['name'];

        $uname = $_SESSION['uname'];
        $idObj = mysql_query("SELECT id_object AS id FROM tobject WHERE uname = '$uname'");
        $idObj = mysql_fetch_assoc($idObj);
        $idObj = $idObj['id'];

      // Create the query and insert
      // into our database.
      $query = "INSERT INTO slike ";
      $query .= "VALUES ('', '$idObj', '$data', '$tmpName')";
      $results = mysql_query($query, $con);

      // Print results
      print "Thank you, your file has been uploaded.";

}
else {
   print "No image selected/uploaded";
}
```

}

I suppose this is ok.. It does store something in db (appropriate size), but I can't see what it is manually.. So, when I try to fetch it with this code:

```
else if (isset($_GET['idSlike'])) {
$idSlike = $_GET['idSlike'];

    $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root");
    mysql_select_db("psi", $con);

$res = mysql_query("SELECT slika FROM slike WHERE id_slika = '$idSlike'");
if (!$res) {
    die("greska: " . mysql_error());
};

$slika = mysql_fetch_array($res);
$slika = $slika['slika'];
header('Content-Type: ' . $slika['mimetype']);
echo $slika;
}
```

> note: both storing and getting images from db are in same file
>   (image.php)...

I don't get anything...
I tried displaying it with:

```
<img src="image.php?idSlike=10"/>
```

> i hardcoded ids but they exist in db

i also tried with

```
echo "<img src=\"image.php?idSlike=13\">";
```

through another php file but all i get is an empty image (with correct src)

I'm using xampp (mysql 5.5.16; PHP 5.3.8)...

Comment: Beside your problem stated in your question; take a look at SQL injection. Your script is vulnerable for it!

Comment: thanks for the mention.. i look into it.. :)

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 1):

Turn on notices and warnings in your development environment with:

```
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

You're doing things that are non-sensicle (and PHP will tell you about it if you let it):

```
$slika = mysql_fetch_array($res);
$slika = $slika['slika'];
header('Content-Type: ' . $slika['mimetype']); // <-- $slika is a string not an array
echo $slika; // <-- if $slika is an array here, you can not echo is like this
```

Comment: i'm pretty much a noob in this area, so a proper explanation of echo-ing arrays would be nice...
i thought that because of: $slika = $slika['slika']; i'm accessing BLOB directly...

Comment: No, `mysql_fetch_array` will fetch an array of strings, they are _always_ strings. If you want to turn it into an object you will have to `unserialize` it with the appropriate method (which is the reverse method of whatever you used to `serialize` it with).

Comment: btw, that php file when accessed directly with idSlike set does output something.. but it's just some garbage, changing it's type to jpg and then trying to open it results in non readable data...

Comment: i'm not sure if i even serialize it... all i do is addslashes before store it in db... stripslashes or unserialize don't make any difference...